# Why can't I add a QGridLayout to a QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I've created a `QMainWindow` class. I coded a `QGridLayout` for the main layout, but whenever I add `setLayout(grid);` this error comes up:

```
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout
```

As far as I know, I haven't added any sort of layout in my code before.

I'm using Qt Creator and using Linux (ubuntu 12.10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is create a QWidget set it as the central widget and give this one a layout. QMainWindow has its own layout already to place statusbar and mainmenu thus you can't set another one directly.

Answer (score 4):

[`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmainwindow.html) comes with its own layout, you can't set that directly.

You *probably* should be setting your layout on the central widget, or possibly not using a `QMainWindow` at all if you don't want its layout/features.