# What should I use instead of QMainWindow if I don't want to use QMainWindow's layout? Where should QMainWindow be preferred?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661255/462608

> QMainWindow comes with its own layout, you can't set that directly.
>   You probably should be setting your layout on the central widget, or possibly not using a QMainWindow at all if you don't want its layout/features.

I have my own set of buttons and other things which I want to arrange in a grid.
**Am I supposed to add my widgets to QMainWindow's default layout?**

What should I use instead of QMainWindow if I don't want to use QMainWindow's layout? Where should QMainWindow be preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details):

> QMainWindow has its own layout to which you can add QToolBars, QDockWidgets, a QMenuBar, and a QStatusBar. The layout has a center area that can be occupied by any kind of widget. You can see an image of the layout below.
>
> [image: QMainWindow layout]

#### What should I use instead of QMainWindow if I don't want to use QMainWindow's layout? Where should QMainWindow be preferred?

So, if you are interested in having `QToolBar`s, `QDockWidget`s, `QMenuBar`s, or `QStatusBar`s, You should use `QMainWindow`. Otherwise, You can just use a plain `QWidget`.

#### Am I supposed to add my widgets to QMainWindow's default layout?

No, You don't have access to `QMainWindow`'s layout. You should have a `QWidget` that contains all your widgets (your buttons for example) in a layout, then use that widget as `QMainWindow`'s central widget, e.g.:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    QWidget centralWidget; //this is the widget where you put your buttons
    QGridLayout centralLayout(&centralWidget); //sets layout for the widget
    //add buttons
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            centralLayout
                    .addWidget(new QPushButton(
                                   QStringLiteral("(%0, %1)")
                                   .arg(i).arg(j)),
                               i, j);
    
    //use your widget inside the main window
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(&centralWidget);
    //main window can have a toolbar too
    QToolBar* myToolBar = mainWindow.addToolBar("myToolBar");
    myToolBar->addAction("myToolBar action");
    //show mainwindow
    mainWindow.show();
    
    return a.exec();
}
```